# Laravel - Change query dependend from the results of a form

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

at the moment I am struggling a bit with a SQL Query in Laravel.

I have a form with 6 Dropdowns which I send to a Image Controller via get. In dependency of what I will send to the controller, the query should change.

If a  is "empty"  (value="leer") this should be excluded from the query.

This is my html:

```
<form action="/filter" method="get">

                                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="brand">Brand</label>
                                                    <select class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand">
                                                        <option value="leer"></option>
                                                        @foreach($brands as $brand)

                                                            <option value="{{$brand->brand}}">{{$brand->brand}}</option>


                                                        @endforeach


                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="color">Color</label>
                                                    <select class="form-control" id="color" name="color">
                                                        <option value="leer"></option>

                                                        @foreach($colors as $color)

                                                            <option value="{{$color->color}}">{{$color->color}}</option>


                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="style">Style</label>
                                                    <select class="form-control" id="style" name="style">
                                                        <option value="leer"></option>
                                                        @foreach($styles as $style)

                                                            <option value="{{$style->style}}">{{$style->style}}</option>


                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="material">Material</label>
                                                    <select class="form-control" id="material" name="material">
                                                        <option value="leer"></option>
                                                        @foreach($materials as $material)

                                                            <option value="{{$material->material}}">{{$material->material}}</option>


                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="shape">Shape</label>
                                                    <select class="form-control" id="shape" name="shape">
                                                        <option value="leer"></option>
                                                        @foreach($shapes as $shape)

                                                            <option value="{{$shape->shape}}">{{$shape->shape}}</option>


                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="year">Year</label>
                                                    <select class="form-control" id="year" name="year">
                                                        <option value="leer"></option>
                                                        @foreach($years as $year)

                                                            <option value="{{$year->year}}">{{$year->year}}</option>


                                                        @endforeach

                                                    </select>
                                                </div>

                                                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Filter">



                                                <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close
                                                </button>

                                            </form>
```

I send this form via a route

```
Route::get('/filter', 'ImagesController@filter');
```

And this is my controller function, the where clause should be empty by defaultif nothing is chosen in the form. If you choose for example somtehing from the brand dropdown and the color dropdown, The query should look like where([['brand', $brand],['color',$color]])->paginate(12);

```
    public function filter(Request $request){

    $brand = $request->brand;
    $color = $request->color;
    $style = $request->style;
    $material = $request->material;
    $year = $request->year;
    $shape = $request->shape;

  $images = DB::table('images')->select('brand', 'color', 'style', 'material', 'shape', 'year', 'id', 'path', 'created_at')->where('year',$year)->paginate(12);

    if ($brand == 'leer') {
        $images->where('brand', '=', $brand);
    }

    if ($color == 'leer') {
        $images->where('color', '=', $color);
    }

    if ($style == 'leer') {
        $images->where('style', '=', $style);
    }

    if ($material == 'leer') {
        $images->where('material', '=', $material);
    }

    if ($shape == 'leer') {
        $images->where('shape', '=', $shape);
    }

    if ($year == 'leer') {
        $images->where('year', '=', $year);
    }




    return view('index')->with(compact('images'));
```

Sometimes it works but I think its by accident, obviously it doesnt work.

I would really appreciate your help.

Many thanks in advance Lars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call paginate after the where clauses. A paginate on the builder object results in a LengthAwarePaginator object. A where call on this paginator results in a where on the pagination collection (through the magic method __call) which isn't the expected response.

Try:

```
$imagesQuery = DB::table('images')->select('brand', 'color', 'style', 'material', 'shape', 'year', 'id', 'path', 'created_at')->where('year',$year);

        if ($brand == 'leer') {
            $imagesQuery->where('brand', '=', $brand);
        }

        if ($color == 'leer') {
            $imagesQuery->where('color', '=', $color);
        }

        if ($style == 'leer') {
            $imagesQuery->where('style', '=', $style);
        }

        if ($material == 'leer') {
            $imagesQuery->where('material', '=', $material);
        }

        if ($shape == 'leer') {
            $imagesQuery->where('shape', '=', $shape);
        }

        if ($year == 'leer') {
            $imagesQuery->where('year', '=', $year);
        }

$images = $imagesQuery->paginate(12);

return view('index')->with(compact('images'));
```